# hide the child parent not child

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Please help me out of this...

```
<li id="4331">Region
      <ul>
         <li id="4332">Asia</li>
         <li id="6621">Europe</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Here is my query if I Click on Region
 
Its a parent of ul
only display Asia & Europe and Hide the Region when is clicked on (parent)

```
i am using the .hide() method
```

here is what i did so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").live("click", function(event) {
        $("li").hide(); 
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        loadChild($(this).attr("id"), event);
        return false;
    })
});
```

my current output is:

```
<li id="4331" style="display: none;">
Region
   <ul>
      <li id="4332">Asia</li>
      <li id="6621">Europe</li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

It hides everything...

but I want to hide only the parent Region 
 
I want to be able to click on it hide Region and show Asia And Europe only.
 
Please help me out with this
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`$("li")` is a collection of all the `li` elements of your page, not just the one you clicked.

Replace

```
$("li").hide();
```

with

```
$(this).parent().closest("li").hide();
```

Comment: I answered the question as I understood it but I'm still unsure of what it is.

Comment: ya i all try this its display both :) but i want only child not both parent and child :) any idea???

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to hide the text `Region`, so you could stick it in a `<span>` tag and hide that.

```
<li id="4331"><span id="region_text">Region</span>
  <ul>
    <li id="4332">Asia</li>
    <li id="6621">Europe</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Then you could use

```
$("#region_text").hide();
```

Note that I don't know jQuery, but I know a bit about HTML and the DOM :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to change the DOM, the text "Region" is not a parent to the ul, but a sibling

```
<li id="4331">
      <span class="region">Region</span>
      <ul>
         <li id="4332">Asia</li>
         <li id="6621">Europe</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

jquery (live is deprecated, use 'on')

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").on("click", function(event) {
        $(this).find('.region').hide(); 
        loadChild($(this).attr("id"), event);
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: as your answer create li tag and span tag not display ul and not hide anything...!!!

Comment: what? setup a jsfiddle if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5521514/2019817) very useful:

```
$('#4331').css('position','relative').css('left','-9999px');

$('#4331>ul').css('position','relative').css('left','9999px')
```