# Set parent to display:none, set child to display:block

Tags: css

Working on a responsive website, I want to remove a certain element, however, I want the child element to still be displayed.

Setting the CSS rule for parent element to display:none; removes that element and all the children. Event if I set the child element to display:block; it still doesn't appear on the site.

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">Some text.</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
display:block;
width:500px;
height:200px;
background:blue;
}

#child {
display: inline-block;
padding:20px 5px;
background: red url(someimage.jpg);
}

@media only screen 
and (max-device-width : 700px) {

#parent {
/* code that makes the browser disregard the height of this div and not display its background */
}

#child
/* the child is still displayed */
    }
}
```

What would be the proper CSS solution?

Comment: Please post the html & css you are working with.

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? Can you show us?

Comment: [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div).

Comment: This is absolutely not possible. You either have to restructure you html or use JS as Vucko has suggested

Comment: There are a couple solutions that you can do, all of which can work with changing of your html. I assume you want to keep the parent and child together, which would remove the idea of having a div with a absolute position that moves inside the parent.  My question would be is the parent doing something that then displays the child or is the parent somehow controlling how the child is displayed within the dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to knock out the background of the parent in certain layouts. To do that, just use

```
#knockout {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;        
    padding: 0;
}
```

This will remove the background, the borders and any shadow effects on the parent item - as though it wasn't rendered at all.

Comment: Not quite, @Jimmy. What I want essentially is to disregard the height of the #parent. Would appreciate more insight from you!

Comment: @Astoria - couldn't you just reset the height of the parent to auto? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: You're a genius, @Jimmy. Solved!

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting all children to `display:none`, and then override it with the `display:block` for the relevant child. Example:

```css
#parent>* {display:none}
#parent>#child {display:block}
```

Comment: I wish I could do that, @Kolink. The problem is, I do not want to hide "all children of the parent, except one". I want to hide the parent, but display the children.

Comment: I don't think this will work anyway - display none forces child elements not to be rendered.

Comment: @Astoria that's not going to be possible.

Comment: @Jimmy not sure what you mean - the `display: block` will cancel that for the one child element that's supposed to be displayed, no?

Comment: Pekka - the OP wanted to add display none to the parent itself, not just the siblings of the content to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 10+ years question, so nowadays one would do:

```css
#parent {
  display: contents;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box