# Wordpress theme remove text outside element

Tags: css, wordpress, categories, author

I need to remove the author and category from a wordpress hosted theme, the only problem is how I hide the text "·by" and "·in" with css. I tried with .published:after without success.

```
<div class="byline">
    <abbr class="published" title="November 13, 2013 2:05 pm">November 13, 2013</abbr> ·by
    <span class="author vcard">
<a href="http:xxxx" title="xxxx" rel="author">xxxx</a>
</span> ·in <a href="http://xxx" title="xxx" rel="category tag">xxxx</a>    
</div>// This is just a sample script.
```

Paste your real code (javascript or HTML) here.

```
if ('this_is'==/an_example/){of_beautifer();}else{var a=b?(c%d):e[f];}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: can you edit your html/php code?

Comment: No, i cant, only the css

Comment: Why are there loads of statements like this, where people can't edit the HTML output at all? I'm sure that even if using a wordpress template, it's not that hard to edit the output code, by using a child theme for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have access to your html/php code you will have to use javascript.

You can find an aswer on this post :
[Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

I am not a wordpress expert, I usualy use joomla but I am sure in your article option you can turn off the author name and category displaying.