# How to override styles and prevent inheritance in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I’m working on a project and I’ve created a page using pure HTML and CSS. I want the page to be responsive so I have used 3 different stylesheets. One for width of over 2000px, one for width from 901px to 1999px and one for width below 900px. I want some element from the 2000px and 1999px stylesheet to be hidden when the width is 900px or smaller, but they contain some nested element which I don’t want to hide.

```
<div class=”parent-element”>
     <div class=”nested-element”>
     </div>
</div>
```

I’ve used the following CSS to hide the “parent-element” class, but it also hides the “nested-element”

```
.parent-element {
   display: none;
}
```

How to get the “nested-element” class back without the “parent-element” class displayed?

I’ve used this code and it is not working

```
.nested-element {
   display: block;
}
```

Also, the 900px Stylesheet is inheriting all the styles from the other two Stylesheets, how to prevent it?

Comment: You have fancy quotes ;) ...

Comment: Inheritance doesn't play a thing here, `display` is not an inherited style.

Answer (score 1):

You can not hide a parent element and show a nested one.

You can do [some tricks to deal with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div), but that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Like Alvaro says you cant hide the parent and show the nested. 
You have to modify your html, like this

```
<div class=”block-element”>
     <div class=”parent-element”></div>
     <div class=”nested-element”></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tip: the `css` in this case may use absolute positioning of the elements to make one appear *inside* the other while they aren't really in a father-son relation but in siblings mode.

Answer (score 0):

`.nested-element` is a child of `.parent-element`. If you set the parent to not display, anything contained within it will also not display. A workaround to this is to alter your HTML so that `.nested-element` is no longer a child of `.parent-element`:

```
<div class="parent-element">
</div>
<div class="nested-element">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If an element is not displayed, then there is no way to cause it's descendants to be displays. This has nothing to do with inheritance.

You can set the parent to `visibility: hidden` and it's child to `visibility: visible`, but that will cause the parent to still take up space.

Either restructuring your HTML or setting `display: none` on `.nested-element`'s *siblings* instead of its parent would probably be better approaches.