# How to remove CSS class from child element

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I can remove display:none from all child spans

```
<span class="tooltip">
   <span>Content goes here along with other spans</span>
</span>

.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
```

What I need is for the span inside of the tooltip span not to take the display none effect, I understand that I could a div for one of them instead but how I have the tooltips setup and how it works within wordpress I need to use all spans. Thanks

Comment: display:block!important is not work ?

Comment: You cannot show the child of a hidden parent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

Comment: span.tooltip span{display:block} will show all children span inside .tooltip who's elements selector is "span"

Answer (score 0):

you most remove the 'tooltip' class
from  Child spans ancestor
you can do it with JQuery

```
$('.tooltip').removeClass('tooltip')
```