# JQuery UI Draggable item disappears on tab change

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI's tabs and draggable/droppable. It is simple tab with three tabs, in which each tab has some draggable items. These item are accepted by droppable divs above.

[image: screenshot01]

HTML:

```
<div id="topPart">
    <div class="droppable"></div>
    <div class="droppable"></div>
    <div class="droppable"></div>
</div>

<div id="bottomPart">
    <div id="tabs" class="row">
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-fighter-jet fa-2x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-file-image-o fa-2x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-soccer-ball-o fa-2x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-plane fa-2x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-file-text fa-3x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-text-height fa-3x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-text-width fa-3x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-android fa-3x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
            <i id="" class="draggable fa fa-windows fa-3x" style="z-index:5;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.droppable {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#tabs').tabs();

$(".draggable").draggable();

$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
        $(this).parent().css("aria-hidden", "false !important");
    }
});
```

The problem is when you drag the item from the tab into the droppable div and then switch the tab, the item will disappear.

I understand that .tabs() will add additional styles into a tab. The div tabs have class

```
aria-hidden="false"
```

and style

```
display: block;
```

aria-hidden is set to false and display set to block when the tab is active and true/none when not.

I have tried to reset these on drop event in droppable() as well as remove the classes, but no luck. Dropped items will always disappear when tab is changed. Any idea where else should I look?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vidriduch/g8ef2vf2/4/)

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By more testing and trying and debugging and experimenting I have come up with different solution. Instead of using clone(), I've used detach() method.

So I have just added this line into drop event:

```
ui.helper.detach().appendTo(this).position({ of: $(this), my: 'center', at: 'center' }).draggable();
```

updated JS code:

```
function initializeDroppable() {
    $(".gs-w").droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");

            ui.helper.detach().appendTo(this).position({ of: $(this), my: 'center', at: 'center' }).draggable();
        },
        out: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: instead of `$("#tabs").find(ui.helper).` you an just write `ui.helper.`, you don't need to find an element you already have

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that e.g. the Airplane is in tabs-1. When You switch Tabs the tabs-1 gets `display:none` and so all his child elements.

I would recommend something like writing the items that are placed in a box above are written/cloned/copied in another element, which is not toggled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)-function of jQuery and use the [ui-Object](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) of Droppable:

I added this to the drop event:

```
 var clone = ui.helper.clone();
        clone.css({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        ui.helper.remove();
        $(this).append(clone);
```

Some styling, or adding new css-classes to the clone has to be done.

If the dropped element should be draggable again, do :

```
clone.draggable();
```

And if the dragged element should not disappear, add the option:

```
helper: 'clone'
```

to your draggable.

Link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gzhjxnc/1/)

Comment: This is a good solution. You only need to check die css an maybe add another drag function when you want the possibility to put the items back in their tab.

Comment: yes, there could be `clone.draggable()` done. Perhaps the helper could be added to his original position if the element should be droppable twice

Comment: @empiric Is there a CSS property called `aria-hidden`..? o.0

Comment: @TJ, this a attribute which is set by jQuery-UI. The aria-attributes are html-attributes. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden) for specification

Comment: @empiric Yes, but in the fiddle you've written `.parent().css("aria-hidden", "false !important");` how can you manipulate an HTML attribute using `.css()` method..! especially, if it's not a css property then why `!important`..? 0.o confusing.

Comment: @TJ oh you're right. I totally oversaw that. I copied the code from the question. That line makes no sense in this way, i updated the fiddle ;-)