# Displaying child div when parent div is hide

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="Child">
    </div>
</div>
```

here parent div is hide **is there any chance to show the child div**...? iam trying my level best but its not getting..? Thanks for the help

Comment: In short, no. This is not possible. If you can explain further your situation, we may be able to offer an alternate solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need display nested content near the parent content? So you can get child content and put it near parent content Like

```
$('.parent').after($('.parent').html())
```

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not going to be possible. It's to prevent any problems that occur with formatting. If you are missing some important formatting information in the parent, the child can't render properly because it's missing the info from the formatting above it.

Basically, no. Not possible.