# how to hide Dynamic parent div except the chield div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parent and child dynamic divs.i want to hide the parent div except the child div(child div is a canvas). how can i make it possible, i tried show,hidden and visibility[image]ity options but its not working

```
var el = $('#wrapper').detach();
$("#open_menu").click(function(){
$(this).append(el);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

Comment: @Gilsha thx for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try unwrap instead of detach

```
 child_div.unwrap()
```

https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/