# jQuery: Hide container, then show element in that container

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a container element with class `page_wrapper`.  Then I want to show only one element in that container with id `infinite_math_container`.

My code...

```
$('.page_wrapper').hide();
$('#infinite_math_container').show().delay(200);
```

Problem: The `$('.page_wrapper').hide();` works fine, but the `$('#infinite_math_container').show().delay(200);` isn't actually showing.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's not showing cause you called hide on it's wrapper, which means that it doesn't matter what you show/hide inside of it as the top wrapper is hidden. Here is the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div

Comment: As @ŁukaszTrzewik said, the main wrapper is hidden. So the child can't be displayed. Is there any reason you want to hide `page_wrapper`?

Comment: @OumarDiarra: The goal here is to show `#infinite_math_container` as the only thing on the page.

Comment: As @ŁukaszTrzewik said, you're hiding the container. trying to show a container's child won't work as the container remains hidden. and also, `delay()` delays what comes next. you should put it in front of `.show()`

Comment: I suggest you to add a div container on other elements in `page_wrapper` except `infinite_math_container` then you can hide those elements and display only `infinite_math_container`

Comment: You can hide all child elements of `.page_wrapper` except `#infinite_math_container`. Ex: `$(".page_wrapper").children().not("#infinite_math_container").hide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @ŁukaszTrzewik said. If the parent of an element is hidden calling `show()` on it won't have any effect.

To fix this, you can do something like this:

```
$(".page_wrapper").children().not("#infinite_math_container"‌​).hide();
```

This will hide all the child elements of `.page_wrapper` except `#infinite_math_container`.

OR:

```
$(".page_wrapper").children().hide().find("#infinite_math_container"‌​).delay(200).show();
```

Which will hide all child elements of `.page_wrapper` and show the child `#infinite_math_container` after a delay of `200` milliseconds.

Both these examples will work only if the `#infinite_math_container` element is a direct descendent of `.page_wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) which allows a callback:

```
$('.page_wrapper').fadeOut(0, function() {
    $('#infinite_math_container').show();
});
```

You can [according](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the documentation use hide() as callback but its just a preference.

```
$('.page_wrapper').hide(0, function() {
    $('#infinite_math_container').show();
});
```

Another way is using the [`setTimeout`](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/) function:

```
$('.page_wrapper').hide();
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#infinite_math_container').show();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempts, but none of them have actually showed the element that I want to show.  All of hidden the larger container.

Comment: With the comments above, totally agreed that if the #infinite_math_container is a child of the .page_wrapper class it will not show as is.