# Responsive(HTML & CSS) : Is it possible to HIDE a particular TAG in a nested TAGS in HTML?

Tags: html, css

```
       <div class="sidebar-menu">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-truck" aria-hidden="true"></i> Service </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i> Product </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i> Agreement </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contract </a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

i want to build a responsive website that if the screen gets smaller i just want to display the content  of "i" (the font awesome icons) Tags and get rid of the text. but it seems i got confuse how to do that sense the Tags are nesting, So i just want to ask if it is possible since i saw many sites already does that? thank you

Comment: just wrap the texts inside a span and hide the span with a media query,.

Comment: I agree with @Aziz Although technically it's possible to turn a parent invisible while showing the children, that's all you do. They turn invisible. They will still occupy the same space as if they were visible. You can find more about it in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, for mobile media query:    `

```
.sidebar-menu li a{ 
font-size:0
} 
.sidebar-menu li .fa{ 
font-size:16px
}
```

you can change 16px to any

Comment: This will not work. I admit it's quite a brilliant idea, but as you can see, the element with class `fa` ends before the text appears. Therefor the css will not affect the text after it.

Comment: Ah.. My mistake. Thanks for bring this. Now upadted

Comment: That will not work either. If you do it like that, it will also turn the `<i/>` invisible. And that's exactly what he doesn't want. I know you're trying, but without an extra element like `<span/>` around the text, there's no way to setup a selector for the text only.

Comment: I think it's working and should work. no need to add span. can you please check? https://jsfiddle.net/05qgh15e/3/

Comment: Well I'll be damned. It actually works! I'm impressed. You'll get a +1 from me for that :)

Comment: This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05qgh15e/3/) doesn't work at all. Although your example would actually work +1.

Comment: I'd recommend putting the code in the fiddle into your final answer just incase anything happens to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the common CSS properties used for hiding and showing elements (`display:none`, `opacity:0`, and `visibility: hidden`,) only one of them actually allows an elements children to be visible while the parent is invisible.

> ```
> @media (max-width: 500px) {
>     li {
>       visibility: hidden;
>     }
>     i {
>       visibility: visible;
>     }
>   }
> ```

When reviewing Snippet use Full page mode and resize the window.

**SNIPPET**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 400 16px/1 Verdana;
  position:relative;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 100%;
  border: 4px ridge grey;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
}

li {
  line-height: 2;
}

a, a:link, a:visited {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  color: tomato;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  li {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  i {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="sidebar-menu" >

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-truck" aria-hidden="true"></i> Service </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i> Product </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i> Agreement </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contract </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```