# hide parent but show sub element while printing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bs4 and have a card. Within the `card-text` I have tables.
When printing, I would like to hide the card but show the tables.

On the card I have specified `hidden-print` and the `card-text` I have added `visible-print` but all of the sub elements also stay hidden.

How could I make it so that the table shows while printing but not the parent elements?

Answer (score 0):

[Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

You can only do this with a little workaround. Have a look at the accepted answer of that Question.

To detect that you want to print and call the function only then, have a look at this -> https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

Comment: Ye, better use visibility, thx for the hint @MuhammadUsman I updated my answer

Comment: Still not working correctly. See this https://jsfiddle.net/ezLb059b/ in print preview.

Comment: yep, I see. Its only possible with Javascript or a workaround.