# override the style from parent

Tags: css, html

the style of parent looks like

```
.ac-container input {
    display: none;
}
```

I want to override in the following HTML5 part

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="radio" name="Displayedchart" value="Normal" id="normalRadioButton"class="options"/>Normal<br />
        <input type="radio" name="Displayedchart" value="Rates" id="rateRadioButton" class="options"/>Rates<br />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

so I did the following which fail ,

```
#normalRadioButton .options {
    display: !important;
}
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#normalRadioButton.options {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Remove whitespace between #normalRadioButton **and** .options

Use Cascade otherwise !important, more cascade have more importance:

```
.ac-container #normalRadioButton.options {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: thanks works fine, any idea how to make the text in the same line of the radio button

Comment: I edited the answer, add "inline-block", see if solve your problem to add text in same line.

Answer (score -1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5521420/552067):

> I don't think it's possible.

Instead of hiding the parent you'll want to hide all of the parent's children except the one.

Also, you'll want to add a space between these two attributes:

```
id="normalRadioButton"class="options"
```