# Hide certain content from a parent element but show child in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following code on a Wordpress Woocommerce website which outputs "From £189.00"

I am trying to remove the word "From". I'm sure there must be a simple way using something like `.price:pre {display:none;}`.

```
<p class="price">From: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>189.00</span></p>
```

How can I hide the word "From" from this code, ideally using CSS? I am open to javascript in the functions.php as an alternative.

Due to the restrictive nature of Wordpress and the code it outputs, I'm unable to edit the snippet above. I have to manipulate the above code in CSS or in the functions.php

Comment: Short answer, no way to do so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `font-size` to hide the text, then overwrite it for the child span elements like so:

```css
.price {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.price span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">From: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>189.00</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is already said to be impossible, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23247837/1587329. Short answer:

```
.price>.woocommerce-Price-amount
{
    visibility: visible;
}

.price
{
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdm4mcx3/) thanks to [@Anthony's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873443/hide-certain-content-from-a-parent-element-but-show-child-in-css/43873563#comment74782370_43873563).

Comment: @Anthony: has been included in answer. Thank you.

Comment: Great solution, thank you. Who said it couldn't be done! Feels less hacky than @Dryden Long's answer but actually his worked slightly better in practise as I had to add some padding to your solution for some reason, so his used less code. Just wanted to say thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```css
.price {display:none;}
```

```html
<p class="price">From: </p>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
    £
  </span>189.00
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the format of your html

```
<p class="price"><span class="from">From:</span> <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>189.00</span></p>
```

and apply css like

```
.price .from {display:none;}
```