# Print a div content and hiding all remaing body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to print a div content  without print all body remaining.

This is not a duplicate as was posted by other user friend.

The  div id is '#folha'. During the print I´d like to hide all body staff and print only this specific div.

This div is inner into many other divs.

I and hiding all body("display=none") in media query print and enabled only div id=#folha with "display=block".

But nothing appears inthe dialog print preview.

What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ryh3G/19/

//markup

```
<div>many other divs are here </div> 
<div>
  <div id="folha">
        <div class="container-print center">
            <div class="color-black">
                MY TEST HHAHHHAHAHAKJAJAJAJA
            </div>
            <div class="paciente color-black">
                <div><strong class="ng-binding">THATIANA NUNES ALMEIDA</strong></div>
                <div class="medplano">
                 <div class="ng-binding">Sem Pref</div>
                 <div class="ng-binding">IRB-APOSENTADOS/EX COLABORADORES</div>
                </div>
                <div class="medplano">
                  <div class="ng-binding">15/01/182018 20:46:13</div>
                  <div>TOTEM</div>
                  <div class="ng-binding">Matr:00000</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="color-black">
                <span class="circle">TRAN</span>
                <span class="circle">REC</span>
            </div>
        </div>    
        <div class="container-obs color-black">
          <div class="ng-binding"></div>      
          <div class="ng-binding">Rx e Procedimentos no receituário com CID. Fratura podemos cobrar  Consulta.Recepção: Fratura podemos cobrar Consulta.Densitometria óssea com autorização via fax 2240.1621.Procedimentos acima 300 chs, necessita de autorização. Paciente deverá apresentar lâmina de pagamento. Observar sempre validade da carteira.
          </div>      
        </div>    
 </div>

</div>
```

//css

```
 @media screen {
    .container-obs{
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
    }
    .circle{
        border-radius:50%; 
        border:solid black 1px;
        padding:5px
    }
    .container-print {
         display: flex;
         padding-top:10px;
    }
    .container-print div:last-child {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .center {
     align-items: center;
    }
    .medplano{
         display: flex;
    }
    .medplano>div{
         margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .paciente {
         margin-left: 15px; 
    }
 }
 @media print {
    body *{
      display:none;
    }
    #folha{
      display:block!important;
    }

    .circle{
        border-radius:50%; 
        border:solid black 1px;
        padding:5px;
    }

    @page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; }
    .container-obs{
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
    }
    .container-print {
         display: flex;
         padding-top:10px;
    }
    .container-print div:last-child {
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .center {
     align-items: center;
    }
    .medplano{
         display: flex;
    }
    .medplano>div{
         margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .paciente {
         margin-left: 15px; 
    }
 }
```

//jquery

```
$(function() {
 window.print();
});
```

Comment: You can't hide the body then display something inside it, even using `important!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Child Div within Hidden Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div)

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work. I did a fiddle with the problem.

Comment: You'll need to re-post the page in a print specific format and then print that or provide the user the option to do so.

Comment: @JohnH I have a fiddle link. I think there is no need to repost the page..

Comment: @Darren Sweeney My problem is not related to it. I need to print a div content wihout the body staff of the page.

Comment: Is that not the same as the duplicate I posted? Also, `I did it, but it doesn't work.` is correct, as I said, you can't do it like this. @JohnH was referring to the content you want to print, put your content on a new page then print it

Comment: Mr Darren, Sorry for misunderstood. I appreciate your tips. Now, I am trying to clone thd div into a iframe and print it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea. You can use a white layer to cover all the body elements and make your div with its content above it. Simply use position fixed (without changing any position property so the `div` remain in it's place.)

The CSS may look like this:

```
@media print {
  .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: #fff;
  }
  #folha {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
  }
}
```

And add the `overlay` at anywhere in your code:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: I´d like it. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

In your provided jsfiddle link you wrote under print media something like that:

```
body * { display: none;}
#folha{
  display:block!important;
}
```

What dose means? That's means you hiding all element except `#folha` but `body *` also hiding inside of element `#folha`. That's why not showing inside element because all hiding by `body *` this selector.

Also I found in your fiddle link `<div><div id="#folha"></div></div>` that means container hiding with `#folha`, so screen is blank.

I added following link where you can see the print effect.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Ryh3G/22/
```

So which element you want to hide for print media you should add special class something like that `.hide-in-print-media` . And write some think like that following:

```
 @media print {
   .hide-in-print-media { display: none;}
 }
```

Keep it mind we can't set `#folha * { display: block;}` because inside of `#folha` not all the elements block, so it can be break the layout.

Comment: Thank you mister Hanif. I got the idea. But, my div is result from many divs nested. I can't do it because my app is a SPA and the divs change from  page to page. I will adopt a div cloning to iframe and print from there.

Comment: Actually then you no need add in every element add class ".hide-in-print-media". You should avoid body * {} approach rather than you can consider section by section.