# How to add display: none; to outer div while keeping the inner div visible in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to hidden some class components in a reactJS application. But If I add display: none; to parent div the inner div also get hidden. So how can I make the inner div classes visible while outer div classes hidden.

```html
<div class="vjs-errors-dialog" id="vjs-errors-dialog">
  <div class="vjs-errors-content-container">
    <h2 class="vjs-errors-headline">
      headline: This is an override for the generic MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED
    </h2>
    <div class="vjs-errors-code">
      <b>Error Code:</b>
      MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED
    </div>
    <div class="vjs-errors-details" style="/* display: none; */">
      Technical details :
      <div class="vjs-errors-message" style="">
        message: This is a custom error message
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vjs-errors-ok-button-container">
    <button class="vjs-errors-ok-button">OK</button>
  </div>
  <button
    class="vjs-close-button vjs-control vjs-button"
    type="button"
    aria-disabled="false"
    title="Close Modal Dialog"
  >
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="vjs-icon-placeholder"></span>
    <span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite">Close Modal Dialog</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

So what I only need is to keep "vjs-errors-message" visible, and the other css to get removed. How to achieve that?

Comment: Not possible with display none. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521387/show-child-div-within-hidden-parent-div

Comment: "So how can I make the inner div classes visible while outer div classes hidden." - that's like asking how you can unplug your computer from the power-supply while still keeping the graphics-card online.

Comment: I suggest that you sketch a example of what you want to see on-screen. It sounds to me like you *actually* want to keep `<div class="vjs-errors-details">` visible, but remove its borders, give it a transparent or solid background or otherwise _elide_ the element - **you can do that!** - use `display: contents;` instead of `display: none;`.

Comment: You can not do this. It is better to place the divs level with each other and adjust the position to be inside the side div.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you don't *actually* want to hide the outer `<div class="vjs-errors-details">` - you just want to prevent the `<div>` element from creating a CSS box. This technique was previously known as "unboxing" [when it was a draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#unbox), but modern browsers support it.

To do that, use `display: contents;`.

Documented here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2020/CRD-css-display-3-20201218/#box-generation

> **`display: contents`**
>
> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and pseudo-elements still generate boxes and text runs as normal. For the purposes of box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had been replaced in the element tree by its contents (including both its source-document children and its pseudo-elements, such as `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, which are generated before/after the element’s children as normal).